# Calling wcf service locally taking more time than calling WCF service hosted on IIS on different machine

Tags: wcf, iis-7, localhost, castle-windsor, tcpclient

I am using WCF service at server side hosted on IIS using TCP protocol and winforms client application to call the service.

I am also using Caslte windsor for DI and WCF proxy creation.

```
var rpt1 = Windsor.Container.Resolve<IReportService>();
var data = rpt1.GetModules();
```

The problem is when I point my service hosted on IIS on different machine (even on different geographic location), it takes very less time to return the data.

For testing and development purpose, I have created small console based application to host WCF locally.

The problem is now I am facing is when client send request to locally hosted server it takes more than 30 ms to hit debug point in VS at server code base.
This deply is completely random sometimes it takes even more than 4-5 mins.

```
 <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomNetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00" openTimeout="01:03:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:10:00" />
          <transactionFlow/>
          <gZipMessageEncoding enableCompression="true" innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999"/>
          </gZipMessageEncoding>
          <windowsStreamSecurity/>
          <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" maxBufferSize="999999999"/>
        </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

I also changed maxConnection like below...

```
 <connectionManagement>
      <add maxconnection="200" address="*" />
    </connectionManagement>
```

I am using same config during both hosting type(local and IIS).

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In WCFService web.config do you have compilation debug set to true?

Comment: Yes... otherwise I won't be able to debug service... then no point of tunning them locally

Comment: `debug="true"` degrades performance. Refer [https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448)

Comment: Yes... I understand that... but the problem is sometimes my request from client to WCF service takes more than 5-10 mins to reach and making it almost impossible to debug any issue with WCF service. Is there any workaround for this.